# Can't save numpy in .npy format in TensorFlow with python as cPickle.PicklingError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

I have a trained deep neural network with a sentence-level attention layer. The network is called GRU as following shows, I wanna get the results of the value of attention (sen_alpha) after testing.

```
class GRU:
def __init__(self,is_training,word_embeddings,settings):

    self.big_num = big_num = settings.big_num       
    for i in range(big_num):

        sen_repre.append(tf.tanh(attention_r[self.total_shape[i]:self.total_shape[i+1]]))
        batch_size = self.total_shape[i+1]-self.total_shape[i]
                sen_alpha.append(tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(tf.matmul(tf.mul(sen_repre[i],sen_a),sen_r),[batch_size])),[1,batch_size]))
                self.attentions.append(sen_alpha[i])
```

Test code:

```
def main(_):
test_settings = Settings()
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():     
        with tf.variable_scope("model"):
                            mtest = GRU(is_training=False, word_embeddings = None, settings = test_settings)
                    saver = tf.train.Saver()

             attentions = mtest.attentions
             att = np.array(attentions)       
             print(str(type(att)))
             print(att[0:100])
             np.save("attentions.npy",att)
```

Results:

Type: type 'numpy.ndarray'

att[0:100]:

`[<tf.Tensor 'model/Reshape_9:0' shape=(1, ?) dtype=float32<tf.Tensor 'model/Reshape_17:0' shape=(1, ?) dtype=float32<tf.Tensor 'model/Reshape_25:0' shape=(1, ?) dtype=float32>`

Error:

File "test_GRU.py", line 242, in main
np.save("attentions.npy",att)

cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.module failed

How can I save the results properly? Thanks

Comment: Why are you even using a `numpy` object array of `tf.Tensor` objects? That makes little sense. Just us a list or something.

Comment: `att` is probably an object dtype array.  That is, an array with one or more pointers to `attentions` objects.  `np.save` uses `pickle` to save objects.  While it can write a numeric databuffer directly to the file, it has to use `pickle` to create a byte string.   My guess is the `tf.Tensor` has not defined a pickling method.  Check Tensorflow for its own defined save methods.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fix your code but I can give you the short version of step by step design from the model definition to extracting values from it:

1. define the model graph. it means GRU is part of the graph.
2. start a session, e.g. `sess = tf.Session()`.
3. initialize variables of the graph, e.g. `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`
4. use session methods to get values out of its corresponding graph, e.g. `sess.run(the_tensor, dictionary_of_numpy_array_as_input_to_graph)`.

The output will be numpy array which you can save them.